# Script tag not loading in Webview React native

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview

I want to load script tag in my webview react native so below is my script i am receiving form API

```
const html3 = `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://g.adspeed.net/ad.php?do=js&zid=91679&oid=14755&wd=-1&ht=-1&target=_blank"></script>`
```

Below is my React native code for webview

```
return (
<>
  <WebView
    source={{html3}}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    style={{marginTop: 220, height: 150}}
  />
</>
);
```

but i run above code i am getting blank view any idea how i can solve this ?

Comment: are you using expo?

Comment: no, I am using normal react native CLI

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe and script like below:

```
    const scriptHTML = `<iframe width="100%" height="50%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        
                  <script>
                      //your code
                  </script>`
        
    <WebView
           source={{ html: scriptHTML }}
           style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
```